# Dynamically displaying the column names

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where I have to display questions dynamically based on the buttons clicked. I have coded a table where in one column I display the question and another column I want the user to enter answer. Now when I save this form data I actually need to save the question id and not the question. So I thought I can display the question in the name area like  `<td> question 1 </td>` and in the value field I can keep the question id.

```
<td> 
    <input type="text" id="q1" path="genericq1" value=""> dynamic question name 
</td>
```

I am getting the questions by making an ajax call

```
 $('#q1').val(data.question[key1].question);
```

Can anyone please hint me a way by which I can dynamically display question in the column and keep the question value in the value field which goes in the back end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard about hidden field? Use hidden field to store your id. And for displaying name use label instead.

Like in your code

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="qid" id="qid"/>
    <label id="qname"></label>
</td>
```

And when you getting data from ajax call write it as below

```
$("#qid").val(data.question[key1].questionid);
$("#qname").text(data.question[key1].questionname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily associate data with an element in jQuery

```
$('#q1').data('qid',data.question[key1].questionid);
```

Which can then be retrieved using

```
$('#q1').data('qid');
```